# Where should I restrict the flow of a pump?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, pumps, pipelines

I am using a 1/2 hp sump pump to provide flood coolant to a CNC milling machine. The sump pump has a 1.5" outlet. The milling machine already has a 1/2" adapter and manifold which connect to Loc-Line hoses that each have a ball-valve for on-off.

Where is the best place to put the 1.5" -> 0.5" reducer? I'm debating whether I should do that at the sump outlet, or if I should run a length of pipe (PVC or other) close to the sump's outlet diameter and then use the reducer closer to the manifold. Does it make a difference?

Comment: Restrict at outlet and bleed off excess if your pump suffers from the restriction.  Best would be to adjust pump energy input, but that's not always possible...

Comment: Thanks. When you say "bleed off excess", do you mean something like a T connection with one end to the system and the other end open?

Comment: Tee but with a valve to "open" (back to sump as solar mike answered below).  That return is usually easier closer to the pump.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would add a by-pass valve back to the sump.

That will allow the flow to be controlled from max to min.

Comment: Thanks! I'll go for this!